# How the COP differs for a Vapor Compression Chiller without the U*A values of Evaporator/Condenser?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-efficiency

I am trying to find the COP of a VCR system. I can reach the COP with using the EES(Engineering Equation Solver), without dealing with the U*A values, i.e. just with the energy balances for the cycle. How the COP can differ, if I incorporate the U*A values of the Heat Exchangers into the model? Is there any need for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is, no, there's not any need to incorporate UA into your calculations. Think about it this way:
The cooling provided by the evaporator really only comes from boiling refrigerant. The heat absorbed by vapor is almost negligible.
To absorb more heat, you need to boil **more** refrigerant rather than getting refrigerant to boil **sooner**.
To boil more refrigerant, you need to run your compressor at a higher speed, which means adding more work.  Since: $$COP = \frac{Q_{evaporator}}{W_{compressor}}$$, you won't gain much clarity adding UA to the model.
Caveat: if refrigerant is not exiting the condenser as pure liquid, efficiency improvements can be made by increasing UA of the condenser.

Comment: a great answer. thank you very much! A second question; what would be the difference between steady(with energy balances only, which I did already) and the quasi-steady (dynamic) model? And do you know how should I dynamically model a chiller system? A third; as you know there are unique COP's for the different loads, how can I obtain the unique COP's for the part loads? And according to your answer, the COP won't change in the part-loads since as Q is reduced the W also will be reduced, doesn't this then make the part-load analysis redundant?

Comment: A couple of thoughts on "pseudo-dynamic" models:  $ COP_{carnot} = \frac{T_{H}}{T_{H}-T_{C}} $.  Also, EES will give you a P-h diagram with isotherms for many refrigerants.  You want to boil your refrigerant at a pressure where the saturation dome is widest.  In other words, so that you receive maximum enthalpy of vaporization.  If you have a compressor map, you'll have a better idea of what sort of pressure ratio you can maintain, and what it'll cost you in work. I don't think you should do a dynamic model, these systems are very nonlinear and difficult to control.